# Why do docker-compose containers stay alive after finishing up command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose for developing django apps: I have a fairly simple setup - one service for web serving and one for database. Sometimes I need to run manage.py commands through docker.

I use following command:

```
$ docker-compose run web ./manage.py migrate
```

which works just fine. But the problem is that docker keeps the containers even after the command was finished:

```
$ docker-compose ps
      Name                     Command               State            Ports          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
seeder_data_1       sh                               Exit 0                          
seeder_postgres_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp 
seeder_web_1        fab run_local                    Up       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp 
seeder_web_run_14   ./manage.py migrate              Up                              

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
61d3aee5bb39        seeder_web          "./manage.py migrate"    4 minutes ago       Restarting (2) 55 seconds ago                            seeder_web_run_14
85e91cb9383c        seeder_web          "fab run_local"          5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                    0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   seeder_web_1
565b01dedb7b        postgres:latest     "/docker-entrypoint.s"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                    0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   seeder_postgres_1
```

This is rather annoying: I don’t want to have ton of zombie containers that were used only for one command. Is there some way how to automatically end the machines after the command returns? I know I can kill the manually but that is kind of annoying.

Or is there some logic behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the `--rm` flag for `docker-compose run`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/. It has been mentioned a couple times to make it a default (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2774 and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/943) but looks like they both lost steam.

Comment: Thanks, shame that is can't be at least configured in docker-compose config file...

Comment: `--rm` normally cleans up exited containers that you would only see with a `docker ps -a`. It should not impact a running container.  Did this stop your containers continuing to run?